# Problem about compact subspace of Hilbert cube.

Tags: general-topology

This is my problem:

[image]

I have already completed part (i), but I really can't see how I can relate *compact subspace* with *homeomorphism* in part (ii). Please give me some ideas.

Comment: Can you use the fact that the Hilbert cube is compact?

Comment: So $(X_i,\tau_i)$ are compact subspace of compact space? How can I proceed?

Comment: The Hilbert cube is a Hausdorff space, so $(X_i,\tau_i)$ are all closed. Their product must then be closed as well. You can use the homeomorphism from part (i) to show that the product is homeomorphic to a closed subset of the Hilbert cube. Then use that closed subsets of compact spaces are compact.